# Getting four bytes from a byte array in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, byte

I have a byte array, and I need to get four bytes from it at a certain location (16), but I don't want to convert it to an integer or anything. Just keep it as four bytes to store in a variable.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943635/c-arrays-getting-a-sub-array-from-an-existing-array

Comment: yep except then I have to attempt converting it to vb.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have say:

```
byte[] source; // source array
byte[] dest=new byte[4];
```

Then you'd copy 4 bytes from `source` starting at 16 to `dest` like this:

```
Array.Copy(source, 16, dest, 0, 4);
```

Comment: @PeterMortensen, if English isn't your first language, do try to avoid editing answers, at least the non-code portions.