# Is GZipStream header reliable across .NET versions?

Tags: c#, .net, gzip, gzipstream

I came to the Q&A [Is there a way to know if the byte[] has been compressed by gzipstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662821/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-the-byte-has-been-compressed-by-gzipstream/26234928#26234928) and some author states (and it's true) that `GZipStream` puts `{0x1f, 0x8b, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0}` characters as header to know if a byte array is a compressed string.

And my question is, **is GZipStream header reliable across .NET versions?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With any GZip format stream you are guarnateed:

First two bytes: `1f`, `8b`

Next byte: `00` for store (no compression), `01` for compress algorithm, `02` for pack, `03` for lzf and `08` for deflate. .NET so-far always uses deflate and many situations expect only deflate (only deflate-based gzip is expected by web clients as a transfer or content encoding marked as `gzip`) so it would be unlikely to change without some sort of option to specify it being added.

The next is the file type, with `00` meaning "probably some sort of text file" Since `GZipStream` has no information on the file type, it always uses that.

The next four are file-modification time in Unix format. Again, since the class has no information about the file–as it receives a stream, not a file with metadata, these are always set to 0.

The next byte depends on the compression method. With `deflate` it could be `2` to indicate heavy compression or `4` to indicate light compression.

The next (last in your sequence) depends on the OS type in use. `0` means "FAT Filesystem" but has continued to be used by Windows as Windows has moved to use other file systems like NTFS. It could potentially have a different value if used with Mono on a non-Windows file system, though that situation could also potentially decide to match the .NET behaviour. (Update: At least some versions of Mono will set the file-system flag to something other than `0` on non-Windows systems).

Comment: According to [this link](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Gzip), the values  0 to 7 for the third byte (Compression method) are reserved and only the value 8 is actually valid. Is this link not showing current information?

Comment: It seems like I should accept this answer but I prefer to wait to see if no one provides more corrections

Comment: @DanielHilgarth the GNU GZip utility allows for the other compression schemes I mention, and uses the flag as I describe, though I don't know of any standards document outdating RFC 1952 which, as you say, lists them as *reserved*. Still, those values are found if you use GNU GZip or anything compatible with it.

Comment: No, gzip neither accepts nor generates any values in the third byte but 8.  gzip will decompress Unix compress and Unix pack files which have a different _first two_ bytes, `0x1f 0x9d` for compress and `0x1f 0x1e` for pack.  When you say "lzf" I think you mean lzh.  gzip will also decompress that, marked with `0x1f 0xa0` in the first two bytes.

Answer (score 3):

It should be reliable, because this header is from the GZip specification and therefore not .NET specific. See [here](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Gzip) for an explanation of these values.

However, according to the specification, only the two first bytes are actually always the same. The third byte is *practically* always the same, because currently only one valid value exists. The following bytes might change.

Comment: It might change if I change how I parametrize `GZipStream`, am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry, it might change if I use other class or lib to compress using gzip.... right?

Comment: Not the first three bytes. But the rest might change, yes

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Probably I'll accept the other answer because it provides more background, but it doesn't mean that you're answer isn't correct. It's fine too

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Sure, go ahead. I would do the same :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: the accepted answer is incorrect as currently written.  It needs to at least be edited.  The third byte can only be 8, and gzip neither generates nor accepts anything else.  This answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

A gzip stream is assured to start with `0x1f 0x8b 0x08`.  There is no other compression method supported than the `0x08` in the third byte.

So if you don't see `0x1f 0x8b 0x08`, then it's not a gzip stream.  However if you *do* see `0x1f 0x8b 0x08`, then it *may* or *may not* be a gzip stream.  It probably is, but you can't assume that.

What you should do with a candidate gzip file is to simply start decompressing it as such.  The decoder will immediately recognize if there is no gzip header, and will furthermore soon detect a problem in the compressed data if there is an accidental gzip header.  You shouldn't have to check for the header, since the decoder already does, as well as check for valid compressed data after that.

Comment: While you're right, checking the header avoids a predictable exception (so it's not that exceptional after all...). So going with your approach means a try/catch and mute the exception if the problem is that the data isn't valid...

Comment: What's so terrible about an exception?  Using that approach assures that it is kept up to date with any additions or changes to `GZipStream`.

Comment: OHHHH NOOO!! The endless discussion! :D We can go crazy this way. There're many points of view about the thing about when to throw and handle exceptions.