# get elements from middle of array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

there is an array in c#

```
string[] arr = new string[] {"1","A","D","3","5","AF","34","TU","E","OP","4"};
```

so how can i get elements from middle of this array like below

```
string[] fromArr = new string[5];
fromArr = {"D","3","5","AF","34"};
```

Do u know any method or any way to do that?

Comment: define middle. how many do you want? is it a fixed size or based on array size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# arrays , Getting a sub-array from an existing array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943635/c-sharp-arrays-getting-a-sub-array-from-an-existing-array)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx

Comment: What are the requirements/logic behind the values that you are trying to select?

Comment: this sounds like a homework assignment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to use LINQ2Objects

```
var fromArr = arr.Skip(2).Take(5).ToArray();
```

The most performant way would be to use [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx), but that code would be much more cumbersome to write and you need to figure that out yourself, including handling all edge cases when the arrays are not long enough etc.

But if you will use the result just a few times you don't need to copy it back to an array, you can just use the lazy evaluation feature of LINQ2SQL

```
IEnumerable<string> fromArr = arr.Skip(2).Take(5);
```

then you can use `fromArr` in a loop or whatever without even copying the data in the first place.

When I think about it you may have the option to use [`ArraySegment<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) too instead of copying to new arrays.

But for the readability and simplicity, stick with the LINQ version unless you have a real reason to use another alternative.

Answer (score 4):

LINQ has some good approaches to this. In your case

```
 arr.Skip(2).Take(5).ToArray()
```

should produce what you need.

A reference is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ for this

```
arr.Skip(2).Take(5).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.copy` to take a slice of an array, for your example:

```
string[] arr = new string[] {"1","A","D","3","5","AF","34","TU","E","OP","4"};
string[] fromArr = new string[5];
Array.Copy(arr, 2, fromArr, 0, 5);
```