# Get following command line arguments (elements in an array) in C#

Tags: c#

How would I get all arguments after the first 3 from a `string[]` in C#?

E.g. from `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` I want `[4, 5]`

Comment: Related: [Getting a sub-array from an existing array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943635/c-sharp-arrays-getting-a-sub-array-from-an-existing-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making sure you have `using System.Linq`, you can use this:

```
stringArray.Skip(3);
```

This returns an IEnumerable, which you can traverse. If you need an array, you can just:

```
stringArray.Skip(3).ToArray();
```