# Deleting Last Item from Array of String

Tags: c#, arrays, blackjack

I'm working on a simple blackjack game project. Firstly I create the array of cards:

```
string[] deck = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A", };
```

than I multiply it 4 and given `deckNumber`:

```
newDeck = Enumerable.Repeat(deck, deckNumber*4).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

when I want to delete last card from array I apply this:

```
newDeck = newDeck.Where(w => w != newDeck.Last()).ToArray();
```

so the problem is that code doesn't removes last item from array, acts like there are multiple arrays and removes all last elements from them. For example with one deck:

```
cards: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A
```

when I apply my remove command it become:

```
cards: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K
```

it removes all the A's from array. But I want to remove only the last item from whole array. Whats the problem how can I solve this?

Comment: In `w => w != newDeck.Last()` you are comparing strings, so all strings "A" are considered equals, that´s why all A´s are removed. (Strings are compared by value not by reference)

Comment: Worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/943635/397817

Answer (score 108, accepted):

To remove just the last element use this:

```
newDeck = newDeck.Take(newDeck.Count() - 1).ToArray();
```

Your solution removes all Elements that are equal to the last element. For a string, this means, it removes all elements equal to `A`

Comment: Instead of `newDeck.Take(newDeck.Count() - 1)`, you can use `.SkipLast(1)`.

Comment: @felixfbecker `SkipLast()` is no standard linq method. It is implemented in 3rd party projects like `MoreLinq`

Comment: Yes it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast

Comment: @felixfbecker This is a .NET Core method. Most people still use the regular .NET Framework.

Comment: I just tried this method (`.Take`) versus Ahmet's method (`.Resize`) and `.Resize` is consistently faster.  And I mean consistently, like I would bet a huge amount of money.  The longer the array, the greater the difference.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko: interesting that it's in the .Net 2.0 standard...

Answer (score 48):

You can use [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) class to resize:

```
Array.Resize(ref result, result.Length - 1);
```

It creates a new array with a specified size and copies elements to the new array. It does not actually resize the array, naming is a bit misleading.

It is actually not possible to resize an array. Arrays are fixed collections. It is by design to keep implementations of array efficient.

Comment: I just tried this method versus Flat Eric's method (`.Take`) and this method (`.Resize`) is consistently faster.  And I mean consistently, like I would bet a huge amount of money.  The longer the array, the greater the difference.

Comment: Agreed.  The speed boost is nice, too.  ;-)

Answer (score 17):

It's easy to remove the last item of an array if you're using `C# 8.0` (released with `.net 3.0`) or above.

You can remove the last item by combining the ["hat"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemindex) `^` operator with the [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemrange) `..` operator:

```
newDeck = newDeck[..^1];  // all items in the array except the last
```

---

Some other examples of `^` and `..`:

```
var lastItem   = newDeck[^1];    // last item in array
var allItems   = newDeck[..];    // all items
var skipTwo    = newDeck[2..];   // all items except the first 2 items
var innerItems = newDeck[1..^1]  // all items except the first and last
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IdSCYR)

Comment: Damn, I did not know this kind of weird thing is possible. Maybe in Kotlin or something, but C#?

Answer (score 12):

@Flat Eric explained why your solution is not working.

Here is alternate for removing last element:

```
newDeck = newDeck.Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse().ToArray();
```

Clarification:

```
[a, b, c] => Reverse => [c, b, a] => Skip(1) => [b, a] => Reverse() => [a, b]
```