# Translate NodeJS to C# to load WAV-format audio and remove some unessecary headers

Tags: c#, node.js

I'm trying to convert .sd9 files to .wav files in C#, these files are basically .wav files with unessecary headers (used in certain games).

I found some NodeJS code online to do so, this code works fine:

```
   var snd_buf = fs.readFileSync(item);

    if (snd_buf.slice(0x00, 0x03).toString() != "SD9") {
        console.log("[-] '" + path.basename(item) + "' is not SD9 file.");
        continue;
    }

    var wav_buf = snd_buf.slice(0x20, snd_buf.length);

    if (sd9_file_list.length > 1) {
        if (!fs.existsSync(output_path)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(output_path);
        }

        output_path += "/" + path.basename(item, ".sd9") + ".wav";
    }

    output_path = path.normalize(output_path);

    fs.writeFileSync(output_path, wav_buf);
```

item: Full path to the file

Now I'm trying to 'translate' this C# without any luck:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.sd9", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string file in files)
{
UTF8Encoding nobom = new UTF8Encoding(false);

string raw_buffer = File.ReadAllText(file, nobom);

string wave_buffer = "";

if (raw_buffer.Substring(0x00, 0x03) == "SD9")
{
    wave_buffer = raw_buffer.Substring(0x20);
    MessageBox.Show(wave_buffer);
}

if (File.Exists(fbdd.SelectedPath + @"\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".wav")) { File.Delete(fbdd.SelectedPath + @"\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".wav");  }

BinaryWriter sw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(fbdd.SelectedPath + @"\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".wav", FileMode.CreateNew));
sw.Write(wave_buffer);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
}
```

Either the way of writing or reading seems to add unnecessary headers / malformed bytes or whatever to make the file unreadable, for example, a correctly converted file with the NodeJS script is 91KB while my script outputs a corrupted file of 140KB.

Comment: You are reading your file as a string. It is a binary file. You need to deal in bytes, not characters and strings.

Comment: Okay, I've tried using File.ReadAllBytes but then my problem is, how do I properly 'cut away'/remove the unnecessary headers from the byte array like I am trying to do with Substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reading in your SD9 file as a `string`. You're then using `string` functions to slice the file apart. Instead, you want to read your file as `byte[]`.

1. Use `File.ReadAllBytes()` to read your file as `byte[]`.
2. Use this trick to "splice" your byte array: [Getting a sub-array from an existing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943635/c-sharp-arrays-getting-a-sub-array-from-an-existing-array)
3. Use `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` to convert `byte[]` to `string` for the "SD9" header comparison.
4. Use `File.WriteAllBytes()` to write your new file.

Comment: Yay, after hours of puzzling finally a solution that works, thanks Matt! :D (And Marc ofcourse; The person who answered the sub-array thread)