# How to get a sub-array from an existing array in C# without copying?

Tags: c#, arrays

My question is similar to [Getting a sub-array from an existing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943635/c-sharp-arrays-getting-a-sub-array-from-an-existing-array) although a little different notion is very important in my case - I can't use memory copying.

Let's say I have array `X` of 10000 elements, I need array `Y` that would contains 9000 elements from `X`, starting from `X`'s index 500.

But I don't want to copy part of `X` to new array `Y`, so I don't want to use Array.Copy, Array.Clone, System.Block.Copy, IEnumerables etc. I want `Y` to be reference to `X - Y[0]` would be in fact `X[500]`, `Y[1]` corresponds to `X[501]`, ..., `Y[9000]` is `X[9500]`.

Thus, for example changing value of `X[100]` would at the same time change value of `Y[600]`. How can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: Of course, you can use `unsafe` operations (like to C++ pointers), but it's not recommended.

Comment: Have you considered making a simple wrapper that acts like an array? It wouldn't *be* an array, but if you wrote your code to use the wrapper instead you could create wrappers for smaller slices of the underlying bigger array.

Comment: *Why* can't you use memory copying? Is there a reason you can't pass the offset around (perhaps as part of a wrapper, like @LasseV.Karlsen suggests)?

Comment: With copying he would have 2 distinct arrays + the overhead of making the copy, both of which could be unwanted (he doesn't say why, that's just my own take on the problem)

Comment: If you can't copy elements, then perhaps initial choice to use array as a storage was wrong? Depends on how you going to use it you can implement `IEnumerable` while having inside just a List to hold/add/remove items.

Answer (score 7):

You could wrap it in another object with something like this:

```
class View<T>
{
     private T[] _array;
     private long _start;
     private long _length;
     public View(T[] array, long start, long length) { ... }
     public T this[long index] 
     {
         get 
         {
             if (/*do bounds check here*/) 
             {
                 return _array[_start + index];
             }    
         }
     }
}
```

This won't be an array, but a projection of one.

Comment: I don't think array indexes can be longs, only ints (in number that is), and I would make the view a struct since it will effectively hold 2 32-bit values + a memory reference, make it even cheaper. Additionally I would make the fields readonly, but other than that, this is exactly the solution I would pick myself.

Comment: Thank you, looks very promising :)

Comment: @xcoder37 For completeness, add support for `IEnumerable<T>` and `IList<T>` as well.

Comment: @xcoder37 even though it doesn't support indexers, `ArraySegment<T>` has a similar concept. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [`ArraySegment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx). Here's an example:

```
String[] X = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};

ArraySegment<String> arraySegment = new ArraySegment<String>(X, 1,3); // will contain {"two", "three", "four"}
arraySegment.Array[arraySegment.Offset + 1] = "3"; // X will contain { "one", "two", "3", "four", "five"};
                             // and arraySegment.Array will contain {"two", "3", "four"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly `ArraySegment<T>` is sealed, else you could easily have extended it with the proper array-syntax, ie indexers and the likes.

If I were you I would go with `ArraySegment<T>` and if it doesn't have the proper requirements, like `ElementAt(n)` being to inefficient, just implement a better implementation. Ex:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions 
{
  // Getter using underlying array
  public static T GetValueAt<T>(this ArraySegment<T> array, int index)
  { // No safe checks here, would recommend them in production though
    return array.Array[array.Offset + index];
  }
  // Setter using underlying array
  public static void SetValueAt<T>(this ArraySegment<T> array, int index, T value)
  { // maybe we should check that the calculated index is valid? Or just blow up?
    array.Array[array.Offset + index] = value;
  }
}
```