# 3 random numbers into array

Tags: c#, random

I am writing the beginning of my program which is to have the computer generate 3 random numbers on the console.

They need to be 1-9 (including both), no numbers can repeat, and I need to put this answer into an array. What's needed in the main method class vs the class.

Comment: shuffle the array you and you will get random number

Comment: Post what you have tried!

Comment: Why is this opinion-based? This isn't a question of whether **blue** or **red** is the **best colour for a car**. This has a very well defined question, regardless how trivial it is.

Answer (score 1):

You should try it out yourself first (site rules say so), but some hints may be provided:

**1) integer random numbers** can be generated using [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) class. More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c) and an answer has been already provided about generation

**2) to avoid duplicates** each number should be tested against the existing list of numbers:

```
array.Contains(generatedNumber)
```

**3) For your particular request**, an elegant option is to [generate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx) all numbers between 1 and 9, shuffle the array and pick the first three elements:

```
var initArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).ToArray();
var randomArray = initArray.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```

Get first three elements and those are random and distinct.

Generally, you can a subarray using the method specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943635/getting-a-sub-array-from-an-existing-array).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below :

```
//range set 0 to 9
int Min = 0;
int Max = 10;

//declare an array which store 3 random number
int[] arr = new int[3]; 

Random randNum = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = randNum.Next(Min, Max);
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: this does not prevent duplicate values

Comment: This also never selects `9`.

Comment: @Enigmativity ....... change the Max 9 to 10 ...

Comment: @derpirscher .... what kind of duplicate value you talking about ??

Comment: @NadimulDeCj The original question states that _no numbers can repeat_. Your code does not prevent this (ie the same number can appear twice or even thrice in the result array)

Comment: Did you mean to reply to @derpirscher?

Comment: oh extremely sorry for mistake .. @Enigmativity

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).OrderBy(n => rnd.Next()).Take(3).ToArray();

foreach (var n in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Comment: Any comment re down-vote?