# Code running A LOT slower on Xamarin.Android App in comparison to Console Application

Tags: c#, performance, xamarin, xamarin.android

I wrote a extension method for `String` in a **PCL** Project.:

```
public static ICollection<string[]> SplitAt(this string input, char target, int length, StringSplitOptions opts, bool trin = false()
{
    string[] itens = input.Split(new char[] { target }, opts);
    return InternalSplitAt(itens, target, length, trim);
}

private static ICollection<string[]> InternalSplitAt(string[] itens, char target, int length, bool trim = false)
{
    var collectionToReturn = new List<string[]>();
    var targetString = target.ToString();
    do
    {
        string firstPart = string.Join(targetString, itens.Take(length));
        collectionToReturn.Add(firstPart.Split(target));
        if (trim)
        {
            itens = itens.Skip(length).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            itens = itens.Skip(length).ToArray();
        }
    }
    while (itens.Length >= length);

    return collectionToReturn;
}
```

Then I use the `SplitAt` method like this:

```
var arr = str.SplitAt('#', 34, StringSplitOption.None);
```

`str` is a `String` with 280474 characters.

When I call the above code in a Xamarin.Android App, it takes almost 40 seconds to complete, and in a Console Application, 1 second.

Can my code be improved in any to make it run faster on Android?

**Note:** That extension method is based on a code I got some time ago from another StackOverflow question I think, but I could not find it again to give proper credit.

**Edit:**

Explaining what I'm trying to acomplish:
I have a String like that:

```
var str = "001#Test#002#Test#003#Test";
```

Doing a normal `Split` by **#**, I would get na array this:

```
string[] { "001", "Test", "002", "Test", "003", "Test" }
```

But I need it to be three different arrays, so calling that extension like this:

```
var arr = str.SplitAt('#', 2, StringSplitOption.None);
```

I got:

```
string[] { "001", "Test" }
string[] { "002", "Test" }
string[] { "003", "Test" }
```

In my real scenario, the 280474 string have 53074 of the **#** character, and since I'm calling the extension with **34** as the length parameter, my final output would be a ICollection with 1561 itens (53074 / 34), each being a `string[34]`.

Comment: It would help if you'd explain what you're trying to achieve - it's not clear to me from the code. But all that string joining and array creation sounds like a perf problem to me...

Comment: Wow, that code happens to be horrible for performance while at the same time being extremely convoluted. You probably want to rewrite it from scratch, while keeping your requirements clear.

Comment: Please, see my edits.

Comment: Are you always running it with trim = false? If not, how does that affect the time?

Comment: @Simon Yes, in this scenario I'm Always running with trim = false.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I've reduced the number of operations required to complete the task. Also I've done the trim initially in case you need it, so that the code doesn't call trim multiple times. It ran about 6 times faster on my machine with ~10k of test data.

```
    public static ICollection<string[]> SplitAt(this string input, char target, int length, StringSplitOptions opts, bool trim = false)
    {
        var items = input.Split(new[] { target }, opts);
        if (trim) items = items.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
        return InternalSplitAt(items, length);
    }

    private static ICollection<string[]> InternalSplitAt(string[] items, int length)
    {
        var collectionToReturn = new List<string[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i += length)
        {
            collectionToReturn.Add(items.Skip(i).Take(length).ToArray());
        }

        return collectionToReturn;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, but I had already found another solution that is slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Based on **@Simon's** answer and **@Jon Skeet's** comment, I came up with a very efficient solution, that runs in 20~30 milisseconds. The array creation with `ToArray` and the string joining really hurt performance in that scenario.

```
public static ICollection<string[]> SplitAt(this string input, char target, int length, StringSplitOptions, opts = StringSplitOptions.None, bool trim = false)
{
    string[] itens = input.Split(new char[] { target }, opts);
    if (trim) itens = itens.Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
    return InternalSplitAt(itens, length);
}

private static ICollection<string[]> InternalSplitAt(string[] itens, char target, int length, bool trim = false)
{
    var collectionToReturn = new List<string[]>();

    var loops = itens.Length / length;
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
    {
        var arrayToAdd = new string[length];
        Array.Copy(itens, i * length, newArray, 0, length);
        ret.Add(arrayToAdd);
    }

    return collectionToReturn;
}
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/943650/5649764) for the section where I take a part of the array.

Again, thanks to Simon for the helpful answer and to Jon Skeet for poiting out the possible problems in the array creation and string joining.