# What's a good, neat way to create a new array from a portion of an existing array?

Tags: c#

Given `byte[] buffer` I'd like to create a new array from a sub-array. A method signature might look like `byte[] SubArray(byte[] buffer, int start, int length)` but I'd probably rather just have a neat 1-liner than a method.

Here's a nice neat LINQ version but it feels like this mightn't be very efficient. Is there a standard library method that does this or would I have to create a new array then copy to it?

```
        var subArray = buffer.Skip(start).Take(length).ToArray();
```

Comment: [`ArraySegment(T[], int, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943635

Comment: Why not use the new `AsSpan(start, length).ToArray()` method from `System.Memory` package? It should avoid extra allocations as well...

Comment: Is having a one-liner the main requirement?

Comment: Do you _really_ need an array, or is a sequence/IEnumerable good enough?

Comment: @haim770 if you're happy to work with spans, then *work with spans* (or memories) - don't call `ToArray()` at the end

Comment: @MarcGravell, I assumed the SO isn't going to change the method signatures for the sake of this purpose. Yes, it does create a new array, but it seems more efficient than its LINQ counterpart.

Comment: Many APIs including .Net require arrays as parameters. Aside from that, spans and segments, etc, as a _view_ onto an underlying array work great - as long as you can be sure the underlying array isn't going to change. Sometimes, that's not the case.

Comment: Yes, sometimes you need an array to appease older APIs. But... even then, wait as long as possible to call ToArray(), and start using IEnumerable internally as much as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ~3000 Milliseconds (for running 10000000 times and after trying several times):

```cs
subArray = buffer.Skip(2).Take(3).ToArray();
```

- ~2600 Milliseconds:

```cs
subArray = buffer.ToList().GetRange(2, 3).ToArray();
```

- ~2300 Milliseconds:

```cs
subArray = Enumerable.Range(2, 3).Select(x => buffer[x]).ToArray();
```

- ~800 Milliseconds:

```cs
subArray = buffer[2..5];
```

This is a new feature in c# 8. I couldn't find any specific name but you'll find it by googling something like "c# range feature" or "c# range operator" or "c# binary infix operator with two expressions" or "Range Syntax c#". See [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range?view=netcore-3.1).

- ~650 Milliseconds:

```cs
subArray = new byte[3];
Array.ConstrainedCopy(buffer, 2, subArray, 0, 3);
```

- ~650 Milliseconds:

```cs
subArray = new byte[3];
Array.Copy(buffer, 2, subArray, 0, 3);
```

Comment: Is `buffer[2..5]` a new feature in latest C#? What is this feature called so I can research it (maybe edit that into the answer)

Comment: Yes It's a new feature in c# 8. I couldn't find any specific name but you'll find it by googling something like "c# range feature" or "c# range operator" or "c# binary infix operator with two expressions" or "Range Syntax c#". See [Range Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 3):

There is no *efficient* way that involves creating a new *array*, however, there are other ways you can look at a *portion* of an array:

- `Memory<byte>` / `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` - effectively this is a "span provider"
- `Span<byte>` / `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` - abstract view over any kind of raw memory (including arrays, interior pointers, and unmanaged memory), but can only be held on the stack - if you need to store it, you need the "memory", not the "span")
- `ArraySegment<byte>` - explicitly just describes a vector/offset/count

All of the above have constructors that take a `byte[]` and an offset/count pair.

None of these require allocating / copying.

If you really really want a `byte[]`, then:

```cs
var newArray = new byte[length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(oldArray, start, newArray, 0, length);
```