# Get consecutive n values from array offset

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, vb.net

I am retrieving values from my array using `arr.GetValue(5, 6, 7, 8)`, `arr.GetValue(10, 11, 12, 13)` many times.

Is there a shorthand for this like `arr.Get(offset, count)` so that I can use `arr.Get(5, 4)`, `arr.Get(10, 4)` to get the smaller array from the bigger array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Skip and Take to jump around an enumerated list:

```
var slice = arr.Skip(5).Take(4);
```

You may find some different answers and more info at these questions:

- [Getting a sub-array from an existing array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/943635/436282)
- [Copy one string array to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/886488/436282)

Comment: Just curious... are these methods optimized for arrays, or does `Skip` have to walk through the first 5 values in this example?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as far as I can tell the answer is no, they are not optimized. You can read an article by Jon Skeet about these methods here: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/02/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-23-take-skip-takewhile-skipwhile.aspx

Comment: @adv12 If you want a blindingly fast method, use Array.Copy as shown in the first of Andrew Arnold's links.